# Using a batch file to extract data from a rooted Android Smartphone via adb shell

Tags: android, bash, shell, batch-file, adb

I want to extract files from the data/data folder from my smartphone.
Is it possible to write a bash script with variables where the user can name the package and save location?
I am not sure how i can direct my bash input to the adb shell?
Can anyone give me an example please?

Until now i have done this:

```
echo please name your package you want to copy (example: com.icq.package)
@echo set /p packageName=

echo please enter your Windows Username
@echo off set /p Username=

adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data"
adb shell su -c "chmod -R 777 /data/data/"packageName"
adb pull /data/data/"packageName" C:\Users\"Username"\Desktop
```

I am pretty sure this wont work because the adb shell does not know the variables. I am not a coder so i appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of a variable in DOS, enclose within `%`.

If the values of `packageName` and `Username` don't contain spaces or other special characters, then this should work:

```
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data/%packageName%"
adb pull /data/data/%packageName% C:\Users\%Username%\Desktop
```

Comment: @obi89 The rest should work if `packageName` and `Username` don't contain spaces or other special characters.

Answer (score 0):

So if other ppl in the future have the same problem: You need to add a ":" for a functional userprompt. Also apparently it isnt possible to pull directly from the data/data folder so you have to copy it somewhere else before.

```
echo Name your Folder you want to copy
@echo off
set /p packageName=folderName: 

echo Please name your Windows Username:
set /p user=userName:

PAUSE

adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /data/data"
adb shell su -c "chmod -R 777 /data/data/%folderName%
adb shell cp -r /data/data/%folderName% /storage/ext_sd/
adb pull /storage/ext_sd/%folderName% C:\Users\%userName%\Desktop\%folderName%

PAUSE
```